# Changing images in libgdx

Tags: java, image, libgdx, textures, coordinates

So im new with libGDX and im making a game where if you press the image it rotates, witch means it changes the images for another.
But i dont know who to do it, and i would like some help.

```
@Override
public void create () {

    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    font = new BitmapFont(true);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();

    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cable_side.png"));
    textureRegion = new TextureRegion(texture);
    textureRegion.flip(false, true);

    texture2 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cable_l_1.png"));
    textureRegion2 = new TextureRegion(texture2);
    textureRegion2.flip(false, true);

    camera.setToOrtho(true, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());


}

@Override
public void render () {


    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    spriteBatch.begin();
    //font.draw(spriteBatch, "Hacking Time", 0, 0);
    spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion2, 0, 0);
    spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion, 32, 0);
    spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion, 64, 0);
    spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion, 96, 0);
    spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion, 128, 0);
    spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion, 160, 0);
    spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion, 192, 0);
    spriteBatch.draw(textureRegion, 224, 0);
    spriteBatch.end();
    }
```

Here's what i have, the second textureRegion on the horizontal and i want to put it on the vertical, removing the previous one.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do what you want so i'd like to advise you to try and read some of the documentation available at [Libgdx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/) also [Games From Scratch](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/LibGDX-Tutorial-series.aspx) have a couple of good tutorials.

But this isn't what you asked so... One of the most simple ways to accomplish what you want is using [Stage and Actors](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d).

Steps to do it:

1. Create a Scene;
2. Associate the Gdx input processor with the stage;
3. Create a Skin to store your UI resources;
4. Create ImageButtonStyle with the up parameter with your original image and cheked with the image you want to swap with;
5. Create ImageButtons with the previous ImageButtonStyle.

Here in another [Stackoverflow Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21494340/1779833) user DannyBit provides a code sniplet that does something similiar with a textbutton.