# Libgdx mouseclick hitting rectangle

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a Rectangle variable and when i click on it using

```
if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){"Dont know what to do here"}
```

I want to recognize that rectangle and do something on it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if mouse button is pressed and trying to search the rectangle it hit.

Libgdx already does that for you in [**scene2d**](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d).

You can create a [**Button**](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html) instead of that rectangle and use a [**ClickListener**](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ClickListener.html) on it in stead.

---

**Reference:**

[How to create a button in Libgdx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488311/libgdx-how-to-create-a-button)

---

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: I created this variable:

     ImageButton b;

and initialized it at create method:

b = new ImageButton();

How can i import the image to that button now?