# Can anyone till me how to make a button In libgdx

Tags: button, mobile, libgdx, touch

Hi can anyone tell me how to make a click able button​In Libgdx
For a mobile device that does something if you touch it

Comment: may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/21494340/4212632

Comment: Nop can't really say it was

Comment: `For a mobile device that does something if you touch it` ?

Comment: Will if you touch a texture / Sprite it should  something

Comment: So you want someone to provide the code?

Comment: Iim would for say if you have a play button on screen and it is touched it would do something

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can add a Button without adding any external skin

```
TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
textButtonStyle.font = yourCustomFont;
textButtonStyle.fontColor = Color.WHITE;
stage.add(new TextButton("Custom Btn ", textButtonStyle));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a minimal example of what you are trying to achieve with comments

```
package com.mygdx.gtest;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ChangeListener;

public class Test extends ApplicationAdapter{


    private Skin skin;
    private TextButton button;
    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        //make a stage for your button to go on
        stage = new Stage();

        //load a skin(a collection of styles for objects)
        // skin is from gdx-skins (https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-skins)
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("neon-ui.json"));

        //create your button
        button = new TextButton("Button1", skin);

        //add it to your stage
        stage.addActor(button);

        // add a listener to your buttons so it does something when clicked
        button.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                System.out.println("I was clicked");
            }
        });

        // set the sgae as the input processor so it will respond to clicks etc
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        //clear the screen
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // tell stage to do action and then draw itself
        stage.draw();
        stage.act();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good but I don't have time to do it at the moment I will let you know soon

Comment: Nope don't do what I want

Comment: What doesn't work about it? it works fine on mine printing out "I was clicked" when clicked