# LibGDX Button does not recognize clicks (Stage + ChangeListener)

Tags: java, button, libgdx, stage

EDIT: First Cemmentator "Second" was right. I forgot to set Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); - Now everything is working as it should. Thanks!

---

My Libgdx Buttons "Back", "Menu" and "TryAgain" (which bring you back to another Screen) are not working.

I worked through every solution that I could find but they still not work properly. I also use Buttons and stages in my other Screens and they all work like a charm.

Do you guys see any mistakes in the code? `CreateStage()` creates the stage and they get displayed through the render Method.

Any Help is greatly appreciated!

```
public class HighscoreScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

private final GameClass game;
private int score;
private String name;
private boolean menuView;

private SpriteBatch batch;
private BitmapFont scoreFont;

private String[] players;
private int[] scores;
private int counter = 0;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private Stage stage;
private ScreenViewport v;

public HighscoreScreen (GameClass game, OrthographicCamera camera, int score, String name) {
    this.camera = camera;
    this.game = game;
    this.score = score;
    this.name = name;
    this.batch = new SpriteBatch();
    menuView = false;
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    scoreFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("Fonts/score.fnt"),
            Gdx.files.internal("Fonts/score.png"),false);
    createStage();
}

public HighscoreScreen (GameClass game, OrthographicCamera camera){
    this.game = game;
    this.camera = camera;
    this.batch = new SpriteBatch();
    menuView = true;

    scoreFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("Fonts/score.fnt"),
            Gdx.files.internal("Fonts/score.png"),false);

}

public void createStage(){

    v = new ScreenViewport();
    v.setCamera(camera);
    stage = new Stage(v, batch);

    if (menuView) {

        Buttons back = new Buttons("Back");
        stage.addActor(back.createButton(GameInfo.WIDTH / 2 - 100,
                GameInfo.HEIGHT / 2 - 200));

        back.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game));
            }
        });

    } else {

        Buttons tryAgain = new Buttons("Try Again");
        stage.addActor(tryAgain.createButton(GameInfo.WIDTH / 2 - 200,
                GameInfo.HEIGHT / 2 - 200));

        tryAgain.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                game.setScreen(new SurvivalScreen(game, name));
            }
        });

        Buttons menu = new Buttons("Menu");
        stage.addActor(menu.createButton(GameInfo.WIDTH / 2,
                GameInfo.HEIGHT / 2 - 200));

        menu.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game));
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (menuView) {

        if (counter == 0) {

            createStage();
            writeScoresToFile();
            readHighscore();
            counter++;

        }

        batch.begin();
        highscoreToFont();
        batch.end();
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();


    } else {

        if (counter == 0) {

            createStage();
            writeScoresToFile();
            readHighscore();
            compareHighscore();
            writeHighscore();
            counter++;

        }

        batch.begin();
        highscoreToFont();
        batch.end();
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();

    }

}

public void dispose(){
    batch.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
}
```

Comment: What is the Buttons class you are using? The only one I find in my project is 'com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Buttons' which is for mouse buttons, but it does not have the constructor or methods you are using. Till now I use scene2d and TextButton, but I am new to libgdx as well (nightly build of mid april 2019).

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488311/how-to-create-a-button-in-libgdx

Comment: i got my own Button Class and i am using "badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing the settings of the input processor to your stage (at least it's not in the code you have posted).

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Note:
Assuming the the Buttons class returns a proper actor.
(see my comment above)

Comment: You are totally right. That was the missing piece. I knew i forgot something... Thanks and have a good day! :)